# Changing content of MvxPickerViewModel

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am writing a simple application that contains a database of items.  The items have a type, manufacturer, model, and a few other properties.  I have a implemented three UIPickerView's with MvxPickerViewModel's as outlined in N=19 of the N+1 series for MvvmCross.  There is one UIPickerView/MvxPickerViewModel for each the type, the manufacturer, and the model (only one is ever on the screen at a time).  However if I update the ItemSource data for a MvxPickerViewModel, the rows that were already visible in the UIPickerView do not refresh until they are scrolled off the screen.  The N=19 example, does not update the list of items in the UIPickerView so it isn't clear that the problem didn't exist there.  Have I made a mistake or has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a work around?

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;

        var comparableTableViewSource = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(ComparableLV);
        ComparableLV.Source = comparableTableViewSource;

        var ManufacturerPicker = new UIPickerView();
        var manufacturerPickerModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(ManufacturerPicker);
        ManufacturerPicker.Model = manufacturerPickerModel;
        ManufacturerPicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
        ManufacturerTextField.InputView = ManufacturerPicker;

        var ModelPicker = new UIPickerView();
        var modelPickerModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(ModelPicker);
        ModelPicker.Model = modelPickerModel;
        ModelPicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
        ModelTextField.InputView = ModelPicker;

        var TypePicker = new UIPickerView();
        var typePickerModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(TypePicker);
        TypePicker.Model = typePickerModel;
        TypePicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
        TypeTextField.InputView = TypePicker;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();
        set.Bind(comparableTableViewSource).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Comparables);
        set.Bind(manufacturerPickerModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Manufacturers);
        set.Bind(manufacturerPickerModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedManufacturer);
        set.Bind(ManufacturerTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedManufacturer);
        set.Bind(modelPickerModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Models);
        set.Bind(modelPickerModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedModel);
        set.Bind(ModelTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedModel);
        set.Bind(typePickerModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Types);
        set.Bind(typePickerModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedType);
        set.Bind(TypeTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedType);

        set.Apply();

        var g = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => {
            HornTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
            ManufacturerTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
            ModelTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
        });

        View.AddGestureRecognizer(g);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [MvxPickerViewModel.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxPickerViewModel.cs) I'm suspicious that there is no call to `ReloadAllComponents` (or to `ReloadComponent[0]`) when the `ItemsSource` itself changes, but there is a call when the Collection internally changes.

As a workaround, perhaps try a subclass like:

```
public class MyPickerViewModel
    : MvxPickerViewModel
{
    private readonly UIPickerView _pickerView;

    public MyPickerViewModel(UIPickerView pickerView)
      : base(pickerViww)
    {
        _pickerView = pickerView;
    }


    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public override  IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return base.ItemsSource; }
        set
        {
            base.ItemsSource = value;
            if (value != null)
               _pcikerView.ReloadComponent(0);
        }
    }  
}
```

Would also be great to get a fix back into MvvmCross...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the awesome framework.  Keep up the good work!  Is the "..." fishing for help?  If so, where can I get plugged in?

Comment: I  logged this issue to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/354 - let me know if the fix works (or has other issues - eg with selecteditem) and I'll get it info the code and add a test app

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having.  I'll let you know if I run into anything else.